# Do a callback after content load with infinite-scroll.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Is it possible to call a function after loads with infinite-scroll.js library?

I've seen a function to call on init:

```
onInit: function() {
    this.on( 'load', function() {
       var ancho = parseFloat($('.imagen').innerWidth());
       $('.normal img').css("width", ancho);
       $('.hover img').css("width", ancho);
     });
 }
```

https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#oninit

Is it possible to call a function after content is loaded?

**EDIT**

Here is the updated code following the answer below.

```
var inf = $('.col-trabajos').infiniteScroll({
    path: '.nav-previous a',
    append: '.article',
    history: false,
    hideNav: '.nav-links',
});

// callback
inf.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
   var ancho = $('.imagen').innerWidth();
   $('.normal img').css("width", ancho);
   $('.hover img').css("width", ancho);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is that option (and much more) events you can listen to in this library,

here is the sample for the "append" function which is:

> Triggered after item elements have been appended to the container

```
// jQuery
$container.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
  console.log( 'Loaded: ' + path );
});

// vanilla JS
infScroll.on( 'append', function( response, path, items ) {...});
```

look into this page: https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#append